# i cant seem to get it to print the Score out when i run quiz() it should show score out of 10 but it dose not

Tags: python

```
import random
import operator

def randomCalc():
    ops = {'+':operator.add,
           '-':operator.sub,
           '*':operator.mul, 
           '/':operator.truediv}
    num1 = random.randint(0,12)
    num2 = random.randint(1,10)   
    op = random.choice(list(ops.keys()))
    answer = ops.get(op)(num1,num2)
    print('What is {} {} {}?\n'.format(num1, op, num2))
    return answer

def askQuestion():
    answer = randomCalc()
    guess = float(input())
    return guess == answer

def quiz():
    print('Welcome. This is a 10 question math quiz\n')
    score = 0
    for i in range(10):
        correct = askQuestion()
        if correct:
            score += 1
            print('Correct!\n')
        else:
            print('Incorrect!\n')
    return 'Your score was {}/10'.format(score)

quiz()

    enter code here
```

So it dose not seem to print the score for some reason please help i need it to show my teacher for my GCSE coursework and i could relay do with passing it i will need to ace this and my exam form my parents

Comment: You're not printing the result of `quiz()`

Comment: *"i will need to ace this and my exam"* - then you should consider **doing your own homework**. You learn absolutely nothing otherwise. If you want to ask questions here, first find out [ask]; a [mcve] would be helpful, for example, cutting out the irrelevant parts of the code (this is the first step of debugging it yourself, too).

Comment: [Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Thanks For the help Guys and i will take the work for homework seriously thanks you guys have changed my idea of school now ;) hope you have a good life.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are not printing the result instead you are returning it. So you could either print the function print(quiz()) or change the return for a print inside the quiz function.

```
def quiz():
    print('Welcome. This is a 10 question math quiz\n')
    score = 0
    for i in range(10):
        correct = askQuestion()
        if correct:
            score += 1
            print('Correct!\n')
        else:
            print('Incorrect!\n')
    print('Your score was {}/10'.format(score))
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are trying to display a combination of strings and variables, try typing

```
answer = 6
print "whatever you message is:"
return answer
```

return is primarily used for displaying variables not strings.